# DotNetZip: Deny removing and updating list of files in protected zip

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, zip

I have zip, protected with password. How to deny removal of entries from my zip file and updating of entries in it?

If it`s possible to deny even opening protected zip without password, this would be the best solution.

How to do this using DotNetZip library?

Comment: Does [this link](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/discussions/251268) help?  Are you zipping with DotNetZip?

Answer (score 0):

ZIP standard allows it by adding signature to central directory structure.
But this is supported only by commercial implementations - SecureZip by PKWare, and some libraries 
(like SecureBlackbox).